# How can I disable 'output escaping' in minidom

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to build an xml document from scratch using `xml.dom.minidom`. Everything was going well until I tried to make a text node with a ® (Registered Trademark) symbol in. My objective is for when I finally hit `print mydoc.toxml()` this particular node will actually contain a ® symbol.

First I tried:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom
data = '®'
```

which gives the rather obvious error of:

```
  File "C:\src\python\HTMLGen\test2.py", line 3
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xae' in file C:\src\python\HTMLGen\test2.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.or
g/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

I have of course also tried changing the encoding of my python script to 'utf-8' using the opening line comment method, but this didn't help.

So I thought

```
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom

data = '&#174;'  #Both accepted xml encodings for registered trademark
data = '&reg;'

text = mdom.Text()
text.data = data

print data
print text.toxml()
```

But because when I print `text.toxml()`, the ampersands are being escaped, I get this output:

```
&reg;
&amp;reg;
```

My question is, does anybody know of a way that I can force the ampersands not to be escaped in the output, so that I can have my special character reference carry through to the XML document?

Basically, for this node, I want `print text.toxml()` to produce output of `&reg;` or `&#174;` in a happy and cooperative way!

**EDIT 1**:

By the way, if minidom actually doesn't have this capacity, I am perfectly happy using another module that you can recommend which does.

**EDIT 2**:

As Hugh suggested, I tried using `data = u'®'` (while also using data `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` Python source tags). This almost helped in the sense that it actually caused the ® symbol itself to be outputted to my xml. This is actually not the result I am looking for. As you may have guessed by now (and perhaps I should have specified earlier) this xml document happens to be an HTML page, which needs to work in a browser. So having ® in the document ends up causing rubbish in the browser (`Â®` to be precise!).

I also tried:

```
data = unichr(174)
text.data = data.encode('ascii','xmlcharrefreplace')
print text.toxml()
```

But of course this lead to the same origional problem where all that happens is the ampersand gets escaped by .toxml().

My ideal scenario would be some way of escaping the ampersand so that the XML printing function won't "escape" it on my behalf for the document (in other words, achieving my original goal of having `&reg;` or `&#174;` appear in the document).

Seems like soon I'm going to have to resort to regular expressions!

**EDIT 2a**:

Or perhaps not. Seems like getting my html meta information correct `<META http-equiv="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` could help, but I'm not sure yet how this fits in with the xml structure...

Comment: Have you tried declaring data = u'®'

Comment: I just tried a lot of things, none successful, updating question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options that work, one with the escaping `&#174;` and the other without. It's not really obvious why you want escaping ... it's 6 bytes instead of the 2 or 3 bytes for non-CJK characters.

```
import xml.dom.minidom as mdom
text = mdom.Text()
# Start with unicode
text.data = u'\xae'

f = open('reg1.html', 'w')
f.write("header saying the file is ascii")
uxml = text.toxml()
bxml = uxml.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
f.write(bxml)
f.close()

f = open('reg2.html', 'w')
f.write("header saying the file is UTF-8")
xml = text.toxml(encoding='UTF-8')
f.write(xml)
f.close()
```

Comment: I don't think he's saying that "having `&#174;` in the output string is bad" - on the contrary, the questioner says, "Basically, for this node, I want `print text.toxml()` to produce output of `&reg;` or `&#174;` in a happy and cooperative way!" and repeats that near the end of "Edit 2" :)

Comment: @Mark: as you'll see I've already noticed that and fixed the commentary. The code didn't need changing. Option 1 does exactly what he wants AFAICT. Do you agree?

Comment: sorry, your update was as I was writing my comment, I think. Yes, it's a nice solution (+1) - would you mind if I added a brief reference to your first solution at the end of mine?  (I think my answer still has useful content.)

Comment: Thanks! The real problem was that I was getting too bent up on having `data = '&#174;'` rather than using the unicode `data = u'\xae'` in the first place. I think I must have got stuck in a rut. Your first code sample has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, what you really want is to be able to create a text node from a `unicode` object (e.g. `u'®'` or `u'\u00ae'`) and then have `toxml()` output unicode characters encoded as entities (e.g. `&#174;`).  Looking at the source of minidom.py, however, it seems that minidom doesn't support entity encoding on output except the special cases of `&`, `"`, `<` and `>`.

You also ask about alternative modules that could help, however.  There are several possible candidates, but [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) (xml.etree) seems to do the appropriate encoding.  For example, if you take the first example from [this blog post by Doug Hellmann](http://blog.doughellmann.com/2010/03/pymotw-parsing-xml-documents-with.html) but replace:

```
child_with_tail.text = 'This child has regular text.'
```

... with:

```
child_with_tail.text = u'This child has regular text \u00ae.'
```

... and run the script, you should see the output contains:

```
This child has regular text&#174;.
```

You could also use the [lxml implementation of ElementTree](http://codespeak.net/lxml/compatibility.html) in that example just by replacing the import statement with:

```
from lxml.etree import Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring
```

*Update: the alternative [answer from John Machin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710373/how-can-i-disable-output-escaping-in-minidom/4712036#4712036) takes the nice approach of running `.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')` on the output from minidom's `toxml()`, which converts any non-ASCII characters to their equivalent XML numeric character references.*

Comment: thanks for your input too! If I was smarter I probably would have gone with xml.etree from the beginning, but I only have a week or so to go before I want this html generation code.. "online"

Answer (score 2):

Default unescape:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
unescape("&lt; &amp; &gt;")
```

The result is,

```
'< & >'
```

And, unescape more:

```
unescape("&apos; &quot;", {"&apos;": "'", "&quot;": '"'})
```

Check details here, https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingXml